# GTK Warnings and libGL errors when using x11-Forwarding on SSH

Tags: raspbian, ssh, opengles

I'm having issues when working on my RaspberryPi via SSH on MobaXterm that I can't resolve by myself.
Appearantly there are some driver issues when using SSH and running programs that require the openGL library. I've tested the problem with glxgears to verify.
On SSH startup I run terminator to have more than one terminal, which works fine except that those Gtk-Warnings flood my original terminal whenever I do something in terminator, eventually breaking my memory at some point and crashing. Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image: This is what I get]

My raspbian OS is updated. I believe I'm missing something out, here are some links of what I could find with similar issues:

["Mathematica startup crashing"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=94&t=131051&start=25) - I would prefer not switching to vnc and staying with ssh

["Problems with libGl, fbConfigs, swrast"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update) - Creating a symbolic link like suggested didn't help, but I'm really no expert when it comes to symbolic links or the commands used here. Needless to say it goes over my current knowledge of things.

Comment: WRT the GTK *warnings*: This are very normal if you run a program foregrounded from a terminal like that.  Obviously the fatal errors are a problem though.

Comment: What's WRT? I'm guessing the fatal errors is due to the fact that it tries to use a localhost x server instead of the actual x server it should be going to?

Comment: "With regard to"

Answer (score 1):

The best way to launch X applications before conecct with a `ssh -X` is adding `nohup` to avoid this errors:

```
 nohup glxgears &
```

And you have the application running, the errors dumped in a file called "nohup" and the console operating because you launched the application in background using the "&"